# I have some question about JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: .allowFragments)

Tags: json, swift

1. I have a question about

```
let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject (with: dataResponse, options: .allowFragments)
print ("jsonResponse ==> (jsonResponse)")
```

I want to change the value
jsonResponse ==> jsonArray but the value is not sent to jsonArray
jsonArray ==> jsonDictionary

And use JSON dictionary to check login next...

2. I have more error

```
guard let jsonDictionary: Dictionary = jsonArray [0] else {==> Have warning = Non-optional expression of type '[String: Any]' used in a check for optionals
   return
} // guard
print ("jsonDictionary ==> (jsonDictionary)")
```

if I​ change

```
- JSONSerialization.jsonObject (with: dataResponse, options: [])
```

have error "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

```
//  function check Authen
    func checkAuthen(truckNo: String, pass: String, imei: String) -> Void {
        let myconstant = Myconstant()
        let urlcheckLogin = myconstant.jsonGetDataCheckAuthen(pTruckNo: truckNo, pPassword: pass, pIMEI: imei)
        print("urlcheckLogin ==> \(urlcheckLogin)")

        guard let url = URL(string: urlcheckLogin) else {
            return
        }//Guard

//      task
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else{
                print("Have Error")
                return
            }//guard

            do{
//             read json from API
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: .allowFragments)
                print("jsonResponse ==> \(jsonResponse)")

//              change json to array
                guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String:Any]] else{
                    return
                }//guard
                print("jsonArray ==> \(jsonArray)")

                guard let jsonDictionary: Dictionary = jsonArray[0] else{
                    return
                }//guard
                print("jsonDictionary ==>\(jsonDictionary)")

//              check  true password for json dictionary
                let truePassword: String = jsonDictionary["Password"] as! String
                print("truePassword ==>\(truePassword)")

                if pass == truePassword{
//                 password incorrect
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GotoPlanData", sender: self)
                    }//DispatchQueue
                }else{
//                  password incorrect
                    self.showAlert(title: "Password incorrect", message: "Plase try again")
                }//if
            }catch let myerror{
                print(myerror)
//              check display username in database
                print("No have user \(truckNo) in database")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showAlert(title: "No username", message: "No have user \(truckNo) in database")
                }//DispatchQueue
            }//catch
        }//task
        task.resume()
    }//checkAuthen
```

Result

```
No Space
urlcheckLogin ==> http://www.testservice.com/Service/CheckUserLogin/60-7625/1234/355750067867310
username ==> Optional("60-7625")
password ==> Optional("1234")
jsonResponse ==> [{ "Result": "Valid",    "TruckNo": "60-7625",    "TruckID": "10"  }]
```

Comment: You are not showing the JSON so it's hard to be sure. Since you never reach `print("jsonArray ==> \(jsonArray)")` then we know that your JSON is not an array of dictionary.

Comment: I would discourage you from using JSONSerialization. Use Codable. It's much easier to use. Also, you'll get more eyeballs if you make it easy for people to tinker with your code. That said, chuck the raw JSON in the question.

Comment: What kind of code should I help to recommend?

Comment: If not recommended JSONSerialization What should be used instead? JSONSerialization helps guide

Comment: Please insert `print(String(data: dataResponse, encoding: .utf8)!))` right before the `do {` line and add the result. According to the error *JSON text did not start with array or object* the *JSON* is not JSON, it's most likely HTML. You can fix the first error with `guard let jsonDictionary = jsonArray.first { ... `

Comment: Dump the URL in an app like Postman and send the GET request. It'll kick back a response JSON. Dump the JSON in your question.

Comment: @vadian this is my result 
```
No Space

urlcheckLogin ==> http://www.testservice.com/Service/CheckUserLogin/60-7625/1234/355750067867310
username ==> Optional("60-7625")
password ==> Optional("1234")
"[  {    \"Result\": \"Valid\",    \"TruckNo\": \"60-7625\",    \"TruckID\": \"10\"  }]"
jsonResponse ==> [  {    "Result": "Valid",    "TruckNo": "60-7625",    "TruckID": "10"  }]
```
but i cannot get value  jsonArray when print  view value

Comment: @Adrian this is my value from POSTMAN
"[  {    \"Result\": \"Valid\",    \"TruckNo\": \"60-7625\",    \"TruckID\": \"10\"  }]"
But i cannot get value jsonResponse ==> jsonArray

Comment: With this output the error *JSON text did not start with array or object the JSON* must not occur when you remove the `allowFragments` option. What does `print(responseData as NSData)` return?

Comment: @vadian i print(dataResponse as NSData)  Result is return value
<225b2020 7b202020 205c2252 6573756c 745c223a 205c2256 616c6964 5c222c20 2020205c 22547275 636b4e6f 5c223a20 5c223630 2d373632 355c222c 20202020 5c225472 75636b49 445c223a 205c2231 305c2220 207d5d22>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data is sent as JSON string **explicitly** wrapped in double quotes which is very unusual.

You have to remove the first and last byte if the data starts with a double quote

```
let trimmedData : Data 
if dataResponse.first == 0x22 {
   trimmedData = dataResponse.dropFirst().dropLast()
} else {
   trimmedData = dataResponse
}
guard let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: trimmedData) as? [[String:Any]] else { return }
print("jsonResponse ==> \(jsonResponse)")
```

Comment: Just replace `let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: .allowFragments)
                print("jsonResponse ==> \(jsonResponse)") guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String:Any]] else { return  } //guard print("jsonArray ==> \(jsonArray)")` with the code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I know the reason why "JSON text did to start ...."
Caused by having a mark  \  in the returned dataResponse, making it impossible to read the jsonResponse value

```
Example:
dataResponse ==> "[  {    \"Result\": \"Valid\",    \"TruckNo\": \"60-7625\",    \"TruckID\": \"10\"  }]"
```

I want to cut the mark . How should I write the code?

Is looking to replace the characters in Swift String.

```
Example :  
dataResponse ==> "[  {    \"Result\": \"Valid\",    \"TruckNo\": \"60-7625\",    \"TruckID\": \"10\"  }]"
```

I'd like to replace with "" how to get:

```
Example:
dataResponse ==> "[{" Result ":" Valid "," TruckNo ":" 60-7625 "," TruckID ":" 10 "}]"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This ia not an answer. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56454146/edit) your question and add the information.

Comment: Did you ever try the code in my answer? The backslashes are not the reason

Comment: @vadian yes, I try to test your code, but your code not compatible with my code

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: If the line `print("jsonArray ==> \(jsonArray)")` in the question is not reached then the JSON is a nested string and my code is supposed to work. However if the output is the string in your [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487807/how-to-replace-mark-to-in-json-value) – a regular JSON string representing an array – then your code in **this** question is supposed to work.